# Unable to load google maps in Fragment- Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier may result in stale flags -

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-fragments, supportfragmentmanager

My map shows as follows: [image: Mapview without the map]
I managed to create a single map before but only in an activity - now I want to create it in a fragment.

**SelectLocationFragment**

```
package com.udacity.project4.locationreminders.savereminder.selectreminderlocation

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.location.Criteria
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
import com.udacity.project4.R
import com.udacity.project4.base.BaseFragment
import com.udacity.project4.databinding.FragmentSelectLocationBinding
import com.udacity.project4.locationreminders.savereminder.SaveReminderViewModel
import com.udacity.project4.utils.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled
import org.koin.android.ext.android.inject
import java.util.*


class SelectLocationFragment : BaseFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var poiMarker: Marker
    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private val REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1
    private lateinit var currentPOI: PointOfInterest

    //Use Koin to get the view model of the SaveReminder
    override val _viewModel: SaveReminderViewModel by inject()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSelectLocationBinding
    private val runningQOrLater = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_select_location, container, false)

        // When the user confirms on the selected location,
        binding.saveLocationButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Send back the selected location details to the view model
            _viewModel.selectedPOI.value = currentPOI
            _viewModel.longitude.value = poiMarker.position.longitude
            _viewModel.latitude.value = poiMarker.position.latitude

            // Navigate back to the previous fragment to save the reminder and add the geofence
            findNavController().navigate(SelectLocationFragmentDirections.actionSelectLocationFragmentToSaveReminderFragment())
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        context?.let { MapsInitializer.initialize(it) }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        mapView = binding.map
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

        googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
        map = googleMap
        setPoiClick(map)
        setMapStyle(map)

        /**
         * Inside this functions we check for permissions
         */
        enableMyLocation()
        zoomOnMyLocation()

        //These coordinates represent the lattitude and longitude of the Googleplex.
        val latitude = 37.422160
        val longitude = -122.084270
        val zoomLevel = 15f

        val homeLatLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(homeLatLng, zoomLevel))
        map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(homeLatLng))

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_options, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        // Change the map type based on the user's selection.
        R.id.normal_map -> {
            map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
            true
        }
        R.id.hybrid_map -> {
            map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
            true
        }
        R.id.satellite_map -> {
            map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
            true
        }
        R.id.terrain_map -> {
            map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    // Places a marker on the map and displays an info window that contains POI name.
    private fun setPoiClick(map: GoogleMap) {
        map.setOnPoiClickListener { poi ->
            poiMarker = map.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(poi.latLng)
                    .title(poi.name)
            )!!
            poiMarker.showInfoWindow()
            currentPOI = poi
        }
        // de bagat o anulare a punctelor dinainte

    }

    private fun setMapStyle(map: GoogleMap) {
        try {
            // Customize the styling of the base map using a JSON raw object
            val success = map.setMapStyle(
                context?.let { MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(it, R.raw.map_style) }
            )
            if (!success) { Log.e("dra", "Style parsing failed.") }
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            Log.e("dra", "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
        }
    }

    // Checks that users have given permission
    private fun isPermissionGranted() : Boolean {
        return context?.let {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        } === PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    // Checks if users have given their location and sets location enabled if so.
    private fun enableMyLocation() {
        if (isPermissionGranted()) {
            if (context?.let {
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context?.let {
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return
            }
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "App needs permissions to run!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                context as Activity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION
            )
        }
    }

    private fun zoomOnMyLocation() {
        val locationManager = getSystemService(requireContext(), LocationManager::class.java)
        val criteria = Criteria()

        if (context?.let {
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context?.let {
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        val location =  locationManager!!.getLastKnownLocation(
            locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false)!!
        )
        if (location != null) {
            map.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), 13f
                )
            )
            val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)) // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17f)    // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90f) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40f)    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 40 degrees
                .build()      // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_select_location.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.udacity.project4.locationreminders.savereminder.SaveReminderViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.udacity.project4.locationreminders.savereminder.selectreminderlocation"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveLocationButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#D71B60"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/save_location"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I have tried the following "fixes":

- doble checked the API and the SHA code on the google cloud website/ and on my program
- I managed to make it work in an activity - but now I want to implement it in a fragment.
- The firebase login system works without problems so I didn't change any api/ setting there
- [Google Maps is showing a blank map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848651/google-maps-is-showing-a-blank-map)
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091313
- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8242
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer
- https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer
- [Android MapView no longer working, even after using updated google tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240724/android-mapview-no-longer-working-even-after-using-updated-google-tutorial/72853786#72853786)
- [SecurityException - GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196715/securityexception-googlecertificatesrslt-not-allowed)
- [GoogleMaps widget error Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72704536/googlemaps-widget-error-unable-to-retrieve-flag-snapshot-for-com-google-android)
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer
- [Google Maps Android: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266626/google-maps-android-java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-framelayout-ca)

Please help me find the error! thanks

Answer (score 1):

After many days of research, I found that the answer posted here helped: [How to put Google Maps V2 on a Fragment using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager?rq=2)

(if admins think that this question and answer is redundant please delete it)